# Indexing data from HDFS to Elastic Search using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark

I am trying to index data to Elastic search from HDFS using Pyspark. When it comes to data more than 50 mb and less then 100 mb the jobs are failing.

Can anyone please direct me to optimize the process? I have four node ES cluster and same with Spark each with 4g heap.

The exception is mentioned below:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Could not write all entries for bulk operation [1/1]. Error sample (first [5] error messages):
        org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopRemoteException: mapper_parsing_exception: failed to parse;org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopRemoteException: not_x_content_exception: not_x_content_exception: Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes
        {"index":{}}
```

The script i use is below:

```
df = spark.read.csv("hdfs://xxxxxx:9000/SOMEPATH",mode="DROPMALFORMED", header=True)
df_1.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").option('es.nodes', 'xxxxxx').option('es.port',9200).option("es.node","lb")\
    .option("es.net.http.auth.user","xx").option("es.net.http.auth.pass","xx").option("es.input.json", "true")\
    .option('es.batch.write.retry.wait','60s').option('es.batch.size.entries','100').option('es.batch.write.retry.count' ,'6').option('es.resource','xx/xy').save()
```

Note: I have already gone through possible solutions nothing worked in my case .

Thanks

Comment: seems like a problem with you mapping or format data  --   "Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"

Comment: data looks fine as well, even indexes are created but it fails to complete the job

Comment: it is probably, something with pyspark connecting with ES. I used the same approach as above using scala and it worked like charm

Comment: OK..then the Index was created....so ...Have you possibility to  identify in which document breaks when insert?...

Comment: its random, sometimes at 22234 sometime 194665

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with Pyspark ES jars.
It works ok if we use Scala jars. So changed my pipeline code to scala and it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

It works when I delete the code: `.option("es.input.json", true)`